# Como importar user32.dll e outras no C#?

Tags: c#, c++, dll, pinvoke

Eu achei vários e vários resultados na internet ensinando a importar uma função especifica da `user32.dll`.

Mas não me sai da cabeça se alguém não fez um projeto com todos os `imports` feitos organizado.

Assim importaria esse projeto e a IDE ajudaria a achar todas as demais constantes e funções.

Ou será a própria Microsoft não fez isso?

O projeto pinvoke.net não tem isso pronto. eu teria que copiar e colar cada um e alguns tem comentários de documentação outros não.

Comment: Bom seria se existisse uma ferramente do tipo DllWrapperBuilder, você joga a dll e ele te dá um arquivo .cs com os imports.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ao importar um dll o Windows tem um processo de resolução de assembly, ele verifica em alguns lugares como Windows\System, Windows\System32, Windows\SysWoW64, no cache global, ou no diretório do aplicativo. Não sei te dizer o algoritmo exato nem a precedência de cada diretório.

Com certeza você encontrará bibliotecas (wrappers) do tipo `NativeMethods` pela internet, é comum fazer isso.

Veja:

https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#PresentationFramework/src/Framework/System/windows/Standard/NativeMethods.cs

A biblioteca desse exemplo é mista.

E outro detalhe, o aplicativo só carrega as dlls que você usar, para ver isso teste:

```cs
[DllImport("fake.dll")]
static extern void FuncaoFake();
```

Se você não chamar a função o aplicativo não apresenta nenhum erro.

Mas se chamar `FuncaoFake()` ele mostra o seguinte erro:

> System.DllNotFoundException: 'Não é possível carregar a DLL 'fake.dll': Não foi possível encontrar o módulo especificado. (Exceção de HRESULT: 0x8007007E)'

Lembrando que o uso abusivo de `platform invoke` foge um pouco da filosofia de código gerenciado. Chamadas de funções nativas precisam de algumas instruções a mais para serem invocadas, a Microsoft recomenda poucas chamadas passando bastante dados ao invés de muitas chamadas passando poucos dados por chamada, desculpe, não encontrei o link da documentação sobre isso.

Se sua aplicação depende intensamente desse tipo de chamada é mais recomendado escrever em **`C++`**.

Answer (score 3):

Não existe e não faz muito sentido ter já que só você sabe o que precisa importar. Além disto seria difícil manter algo atualizado e que atendesse a versão correta.

E se está querendo importar tudo e não vai usar, está fazendo algo errado. O fato de existir várias coisas não significa que tudo deva estar disponível para uso. O próprio uso de importação de conteúdo não gerenciado deve ser feito com parcimônia. Seguindo isto não vai dar muito trabalho.

Imagine algo como o P/Invoke que usa isto de forma intensa não fez, é porque não deve fazer. Mas ele é a fonte que vai te ajudar.

Se quer saber tudo o que existe deve olhar na documentação.

Comment: Adicionar uma biblioteca ao repositório não é importar tudo. Além disso estamos falando de P/Invoke ou seja são apenas cabeçalhos a DLL vai ser usada adicionada de qualquer forma. O que seria bom é devido as constantes. Quanto a documentação realmente é uma boa todos usarem, podemos aproveitar e desabilitar o auto-completar do Visual Studio e programar no VI. a cada projeto abrir documentação e fazer copia e cola de constantes e cabeçalhos.